# How would I call a global function callback in the scope of a angularjs controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to create something like this [g+ login directive](https://github.com/sirkitree/angular-directive.g-signin), which essentially adds something like

```
<span id="signinButton">
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="signinCallback"
    data-clientid="CLIENT_ID"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
  </span>
</span>
```

but I'm wondering how I add the `data-callback` function as a controller scope function?

Currently it's just a global function.

Answer (score 4):

See if this works for you:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.signinCallack = function() { ... };
    window.signinCallback = $scope.signinCallback;
}
```